# Map Method not returning data on Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, next.js

I'm trying to do a simple Map Method, the data 1,2,3,4,5 can be successfully shown in console.log, but not showing on the website.

```
import React from 'react'

export default function secretStashScreen() {
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  return (
    <div>
    {numbers.map((number)=>{<div>{number}</div>}) 
    }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Warning code after compiled:

```
warn  - Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload. Read more: https://nextjs.org/d
Error: Aborted because ./pages/secret-stash.js is not accepted
Update propagation: ./pages/secret-stash.js -> ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webp    at applyHandler (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=16572
    at http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1657263030521:564:2
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

Is there anything I did wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove brackets in `map` for returning values

```
numbers.map((number)=><div>{number}</div>)
```

If you want to keep brackets, you should have `return` explicitly

```
numbers.map((number)=>{return <div>{number}</div>})
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove your {} bracket

```
{numbers.map((number)=><div>{number}</div>)}
```